# Candlestick Chart with dates and time on x-axis

Tags: swift, datetime, charts, axis-labels, candlestick-chart

I am trying to create an candlestick chart using Charts Framework using with Codable as JSON passing myclass can be shown as :

```
struct ChartDataPair: Codable {
var DateTime: String  = ""
var Open: Double = 0.0
var High: Double = 0.0
var Low: Double = 0.0
var Close: Double = 0.0
}
```

Which creates an array of chartDataPairs as shown :

```
struct ChartData: Codable {
var chartDataPairs: [ChartDataPair]
}
```

The value that I am fetching will be shows below a bit as example :

```
 {"chartDataPairs":
               [{
              "DateTime": "2018/10/1 10:00:01",
              "Open": 50.05,
              "High": 50.05,
              "Low": 49.00,
              "Close":49.00
              },
              {
              "DateTime": "2018/10/1 10:05:02",
              "Open": 51.05,
              "High": 54.06,
              "Low": 40.00,
              "Close":45.06
              },
              {
              "DateTime": "2018/10/1 10:10:02",
              "Open": 50.05,
              "High": 64.06,
              "Low": 40.00,
              "Close":58.06
              }]
}
```

The data is just a sample so just wrote 3 values. Now I have to fetch only time and convert the DateTime String to Double to plot it in x-axis of the charts. For with I m using :

```
var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []
guard let financialData = dataChart.self else {
return
}
for chartData in financialData{
let open = chartData.Open
let close = chartData.Close
let high = chartData.High
let low = chartData.Low
let datetime = chartData.DateTime
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "YYYY/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"
let yourDate = formatter.date(from: datetime)
formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
let myStringafd = formatter.string(from: yourDate!)

let time = myStringafd
let components = time.characters.split { $0 == ":" } .map { (x) -> Int in return Int(String(x))! }

let hours = components[0]
let minutes = components[1]

let double1 = Double("\(hours).\(minutes)")

let dataEntry = CandleChartDataEntry(x: double1! , shadowH: high, shadowL: low, open: open, close: close)
dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
}
    let chartDataSet = CandleChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "")

chartDataSet.axisDependency = .left
chartDataSet.drawIconsEnabled = false
chartDataSet.shadowColor = .darkGray
chartDataSet.shadowWidth = 0.7
chartDataSet.decreasingColor = .red
chartDataSet.decreasingFilled = true   // fill up the decreasing field color
chartDataSet.increasingColor = UIColor(red: 122/255, green: 242/255, blue: 84/255, alpha: 1)
chartDataSet.increasingFilled = true  // fill up the increasing field color
chartDataSet.neutralColor = .blue
chartDataSet.barSpace = 1.0
chartDataSet.drawValuesEnabled = false

let chartData = CandleChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)
candlestickView.data = chartData
```

I know that the conversion of the time to double ins't correct as per it is needed, Here I need some help on converting the datetime to double value.

The second issue is the bar width of the candlestick, I am unable to decrease the width of the candlestick.

And I want to fill up the x-axis with the time value like HH:MM with certain intervals like 15 mins, 50 mins, 4 hrs etc.

For which I followed few questions and suggestions here in given link below : 
[iOS-Charts Library: x-axis labels without backing data not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51333345/ios-charts-library-x-axis-labels-without-backing-data-not-showing)

On this issue: `candlestickView.xAxisRenderer = XAxisWeekRenderer()`

isn't working. It is calling for viewporthandler, x-axis and transformation.

Though I can get the custom labels from the custom IAxisValueFormatter. The interval between the two values in the x-axis is not what I wanted it to be like in 15 mins or 50 mins or 4 hrs etc.

[ios Charts 3.0 - Align x labels (dates) with plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41720445/ios-charts-3-0-align-x-labels-dates-with-plots)

On the above mentioned link I am unable to get the `minTimeInterval 
 and referenceTimeInterval`

Basically What I want to do here is plot the hour and minute form the string that I am fetching from the JSON in x-axis and create a custom interval in between the values of x-axis while creating the custom x-axis labels.

My chart is currently shown as : 
[Candlestick Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ka4NY.png)

Comment: with reference to Chirag's answer I have managed to get the x-axis value from the dateTime string as my DateTime from JSON is already in String format. 
Now the issue is the conversion of DateTime to Double.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have same thing to display so I used this way to display the data

```
        let xAxis = chartView.xAxis
        var dataPoints = [String]()
        for i in 0 ..< arrData.count
        {


            let timeStampFrom = arrData[i].time
            dataPoints.append(self.stringFromTimestamp(timeStampFrom, strDateFormat: "h a"))

        }
        xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values:dataPoints)
        xAxis.setLabelCount(5, force: false)
```

Some needed function

```
func stringFromTimestamp(_ timeInterval : Double ,strDateFormat : String)->String 
    {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        self.setDateFormat(dateFormatter,dateFormat: strDateFormat)
        let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(timeInterval))
        return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    }
```

here is the output

[image]

Comment: There is a problem when using this line inside your function mentioned `self.setDateFormat(dateFormatter, dateFormat: strDateFormat)`
and when I try to use the code above and get datetime from the array it gives a error saying: Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Double'